# Display Jenkins Plots on Project Homepage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using the PLOT plugin in Jenkins, and it creates 'Plots' link under the left hand top links panel. What I am looking for is display these plots on the Homepage of the project. Whenever any user visits the home page of the project, he/ she should be able to see the plots readily (without navigating to the build/ workspace).

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know of a way to configure the Plot plugin to display on the project page (as you can for compiler warnings), you can put the Plot images in the project's description along with other basic HTML formatting:

```
<p> Here are some plots:
  <img src="plot/getPlot?index=0&width=400&height=300"/>
</p>
```

I believe the *index* argument allows you to select among multiple plots.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31260573/9993205) answer.
Alternative for those with Markdown formatter:

```
    currentBuild.description += "\n\n![Plot](${env.JOB_URL}/plot/getPlot?index=0&width=400&height=300)\n\n"
```

Actual URL can be taken from the address of the image in "Plots" section